# Cant make bottom pyramid for diamond pattern

Tags: javascript

Hi I just started javascript today for a school task.I am tasked to make a diamond pattern with stars but I couldnt understand how to make the bottom pyramid

I have tried changing things up, this code worked in my mind but didnt excecute properly.
Here is the code that I've made

```js
function clicked() {
  var x = document.getElementById("num").value;
  if (x < 50) {
    document.write("Your Number is: " + x + "<br />Your number is lower than 50<br />");
  } else if (x > 50) {
    document.write("Your Number is: " + x + "<br />Your number is more than50<br />");
  } else {
    document.write("Your Number is: " + x + "<br />Your number is equal to 50<br />");
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    for (var k = 1; k <= x - i; k++) {
      document.write("&nbsp;");
    }
    for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      document.write("*");
    }
    document.write("<br/>");
  }
  var m = 1;
  for (var l = x - m; l <= x - m; m++) {
    for (var n = 1; n <= l; n++) {
      document.write("*");
    }
    document.write("<br/>");
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
<input type="number" id="num" placeholder="Enter Number">
<br>
<button onclick="clicked()">SUBMIT</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made minor modifications to your code. You almost had it. I'd reuse the same nested for loops as is. Just change the top level for loops.

The top of pyramid runs for:

```
    for(var i=1; i<=x;i++)
```

And the bottom pyramid runs for:

```
    for(var i=x-1; i>=1; i--)
```

You should think of moving the duplicate nested code into a function and pass the value of `i` as an argument to the function.

```js
function clicked() {
  var x = document.getElementById("num").value;
  if (x < 50) {
    document.write("Your Number is: " + x + "<br />Your number is lower than 50<br />");
  } else if (x > 50) {
    document.write("Your Number is: " + x + "<br />Your number is more than50<br />");
  } else {
    document.write("Your Number is: " + x + "<br />Your number is equal to 50<br />");
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    for (var k = 1; k <= x - i; k++) {
      document.write("&nbsp;");
    }
    for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      document.write("*");
    }
    document.write("<br/>");
  }
  for (var i = x - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    for (var k = 1; k <= x - i; k++) {
      document.write("&nbsp;");
    }
    for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      document.write("*");
    }
    document.write("<br/>");
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
<input type="number" id="num" placeholder="Enter Number">
<br>
<button onclick="clicked()">SUBMIT</button>
</body>
```